# Keep checkboxes in html table algined

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

Consider a simple centered aligned table, with some check boxes

Clicking a button will automatically select some check boxes and ADD some dynamic text next to check boxes. Now the check boxes are not aligned any more and the table looks weird.

```
$('#add').click(function () {
    $('#bike').attr('checked','checked').after("<span>Good Selection</span>");
    $('#airplean').attr('checked','checked').after("<span>Woow</span>");

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m9884jy7/1/
[image: Table]

In plain html this can be fixed it by adding extra column....

But Please consider that I have simplified the sample and I can not add column :(

I am looking for css solution, or may be a hint that can be used. Also as I have the id of checkboxes, I could add any html DOM which can help correct alignment.

Comment: You can wrap the `input + span` inside a div which has `text-align:left;`

Comment: see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/azizn/oztsxa9u/2/

Comment: we see your point @Aziz, but this is not flexible solution. You have to predefine width

Comment: Is it important that the column is centre aligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP asked for simple CSS solution

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50%
}
td>span {
  float: left;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xdrebn2d/)

Comment: Yes that works, however, technically speaking, the checkbox is not exactly centered. See [this photo](http://puu.sh/nisCE/f1facf3352.png). It might be minor in this case but the general approach does not consider the actual width of the element.

Answer (score 2):

here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/m9884jy7/2/

first thing you should do, is to add a span near every checkbox, you have - so add an empty one near car:

```
$('#car').attr('checked','checked').after("<span></span>");
```

and then add this css, to set a default width to a span:

```
td span{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 200px;
    padding-left:3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok after investing some thought to it I figured out a solution, basically you'd have a wrapper with relative position then the span would get absolute positioning.. pretty simple actually, here is the code: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azizn/pz6q7jun/)

```js
$('#add').click(function() {
  $('#bike').attr('checked', 'checked').after("<span>Good Selection</span>");
  $('#airplean').attr('checked', 'checked').after("<span>Woow</span>");
});
```

```css
table,
td {
  text-align: center
}
td > div {
  position: relative;
}
td > div > span {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id='bike'>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="car">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill</td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="airplean">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" id="add">Select Some</button>
```

It is flexible however the only drawback is if the text length is bigger than the container, word wrapping may occur

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you are using jQuery anyway, try this:

```js
$('#add').click(function() {
  $('#bike').attr('checked', 'checked').after("<span>Good Selection</span>");
    $('#car').after("<span></span>");
  $('#airplean').attr('checked', 'checked').after("<span>Woow        </span>");

  var widest = 0;
  $('table').find('span').each(function() {
    widest = Math.max(widest, $(this).outerWidth());
  }).width(widest);
});
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id='bike'>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="airplean">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" id="add">Select Some</button>
```

It doesn't use a defined width initially, but jQuery calculates one. Unfortunately with my method you will have to add a `span` to all items: regardless if checked or not. You may have noticed I removed the `border:1` attribute as well. It is deprecated for HTML5 so you may as well use CSS.